# How to prevent a jQuery after() from inserting html more than once on radio button clicks?

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button, flags, multiple-instances

I have to insert a button if there are items showing out of stock. The problem is that every time I click a radio button that shows other colors/sizes out of stock the button inserts again...

```
var button = '<button class="btn btn-secondary button button-column find-a-store-btn" type="button" name="button" id="findStoreBtn" onclick="window.location = \'http://www.davidsbridal.com/DBIAjaxStoreLocatorDisplayView?catalogId=10051&langId=-1&storeId=10052\'" wairole="button" role="button" title="Find A Store">\
          <p class="sans-bold-uppercase btn-link" id="productPageFindAStore" style="\
        Padding-top: 10px;\
        Padding-bottom: 10px;">\
            <span class="btn-label" aria-label="Find A Store">Find A Store</span>\
            </p>\
      </button>';

function insertbtn () {
  ($('.pdp-favorite-container').after(button));
   };

//out of stock logic keeps inserting button on every radio button clicks
if ($('input:.out-of-stock').is(':visible')) {
    ($('.pdp-favorite-container').one(insertbtn()));
};
```

Comment: When is the visible logic being ran?  Also you have an issue with `.one(insertbtn())`.  That is executing the function immediately.  Take the `()` off the method so it's not being invoked.

Comment: The :visible logic runs anytime a size is out of stock. When a user switches colors via the radio buttons and new sizes display out of stock, the button inserts again.